# How to read content from an HTTP url from within a PWA without getting the "mixed content" error

Tags: typescript, google-chrome, fetch, progressive-web-apps, mixed-content

I develop a Progressive Web Application (served from a HTTPS url) in React/Typescript that will be run in Chrome on a tablet in offline mode. It will be used to collect data from measuring devices.

It will work as follows:

- On the tablet runs an app of the manufacturer of the measuring device that reads out via bluetooth the measurements the device collected
- That app "presents"/"serves" that data on eg. the url http://localhost:53757/data
- So when on the tablet you navigate with a browser to that url you see that (plain text or json) data
- The React app that I write should be able to "read in" that data and process it

So I tried to programmatically fetch that data from that url http://localhost:53757/data (using the *fetch* call) but (of course) I get the error

*"Mixed Content: The page at 'https://blablablah' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://localhost:53757/data'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS."*

I already read several articles about CORS and tried to workaround that problem, but I don't find a working solution.

1. Serving the content over HTTPS is no option (The manufacturers app
   serves it over HTTP and I can't make any changes on the server side)
2. Writing some backend server code of my own that gets that data from that url and serves (=passes) it to my application is impossible since my PWApplication should work offline (and hence the backend is not reachable)
3. In development mode I prefix the url with eg. https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/ which works, but a) that is no good solution for production and b) won't work offline

My questions:

1. Is it possible or not to bypass Chrome blocking mixed content?
2. If it is, how should that be done given the circumstances described above?

Thanks in advance for any attempt in trying to help.

Comment: HTTPS is not optional for a valid PWA. It is a core requirement.

Comment: So that's a "no" to my first question?

Comment: Yes. All content should be HTTPS. Mixed content will cause more work that is usually not worth the effort.

Comment: >> Mixed content will cause more work that is usually not worth the effort.
So, that is saying it IS possible. That's a "yes" to my first question.
Then what's the answer to my 2nd question?
>> All content should be HTTPS.
I see, but I don't have control over that part, as you can read in my description of my situation. The data is made available by the manufacturer of the metering device on a HTTP url.

Comment: It should be possible to run a local proxy on the android device to translate between http and https - I'm looking into it for a project of my own.